# div width not working

Tags: html, css, width, padding

I tried to set the width and padding of the divs by pixels in all directions to make them fit together but its not working in any way I try. and when I zoom in and out the width of everything changes. I feel I am doing it the wrong way, is there another easier way people adjust the sizes and positions of the elements in page?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruavcstx/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .background {
        background-color: #2ECCFA;
}
#signupform {
            clear: both;
            background-color: #e9c85d;
            display: table;
            padding: 33px 29px 33px 29px;
}

#loginform { 
            background-color: #4daf7c;
            display: table;
            clear: both;
            padding: 0px;
}

.username {
            padding: 15px 35px ;
            display: table;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 150px;
            clear: both;
}

.hidden {
        display: none !important;
}

.password {
            padding: 15px 35px ;
            display: table;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 150px;
            margin: 0;
}
#loginbtn {
            padding: 15px 39px ;
            background-color:#404241;
            display: table;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 150px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block !important;


}
#logintab {
        border: 5px solid #4daf7c;
        background-color: #4daf7c;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0px;
}
#signuptab {
        border: 5px solid #e9c85d;
        background-color: #e9c85d;
        padding: 15px 14px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline;
}
#skiptab {
        border: 5px solid #404241;
        background-color: #404241;
        padding: 15px 12px 15px 12px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0px;
        color: red;
}



#signupbtn {
            padding: 5px 39px ;
            background-color:#404241;
            display: table;
            text-align: center;
            width: 150px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block !important;
            color: red;

}

#signupform p, #loginform p {
                            display: inline;
                            color: red;

}
        </style>

    </head>

    <body class="background">

        <div id="loginsignupform">
            <div class="tabs">
                <div id="logintab"> login </div>
                <div id="signuptab"> sign up </div>
                <div id="skiptab"> skip </div>          
            </div>

            <div>
                <div id="loginform"> 

                    <div class="username">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="password">

                        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"/>
                        <p> invalid username or password! </p>
                    </div>

                    <p id="loginbtn"> login </p>

                </div>

                <div id="signupform" >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="full name" name="name" /><br>
                    <p> full name is required </p><br>
                    <input type="username" placeholder="username" name="username" /><br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail"/><br>                   
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" /><br>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="re-enter password" name="password1" /><br>
                </div>

                <div id="signupbtn">    
                        <p > sign up </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u put in fiddle and provide link

Comment: It honestly looks like everything is working in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruavcstx/

Comment: @CBauer the green login div is not aligned with the tabs on the top

Comment: You've set the child elements in that div to 150px width and given them 35px of padding on the left and right. That is forcing the parent to be wider than the tabs at the top of the control.

Comment: @CBauer I had several trials of what you have just said but it doesn't go with all browsers

Comment: Try the fiddle in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, try these changes in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruavcstx/1/

I changed -
 username/password class

- display: block
- padding-top: 35px; (no other setting)
- width: 100%;

And I made a minor change in the html (placed a `<br/>` after the password textbox so the error comes up on the next line).

```
.background {
            background-color: #2ECCFA;
 }
 #signupform {
      clear: both;
      background-color: #e9c85d;
      display: table;
      padding: 33px 29px 33px 29px;
}

#loginform { 
            background-color: #4daf7c;
            display: table;
            clear: both;
            padding: 0px;
    width: 150px;
}

.username {
    padding-top: 15px
    display: block;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            clear: both;
}

.hidden {
        display: none !important;
}

.password {
            padding-top: 15px;
    display: block;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 100%;
}
#loginbtn {
            padding: 15px 39px ;
            background-color:#404241;
            display: table;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 150px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block !important;


}
#logintab {
        border: 5px solid #4daf7c;
        background-color: #4daf7c;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0px;
}
#signuptab {
        border: 5px solid #e9c85d;
        background-color: #e9c85d;
        padding: 15px 14px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline;
}
#skiptab {
        border: 5px solid #404241;
        background-color: #404241;
        padding: 15px 12px 15px 12px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0px;
        color: red;
}



#signupbtn {
            padding: 5px 39px ;
            background-color:#404241;
            display: table;
            text-align: center;
            width: 150px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block !important;
            color: red;

}

#signupform p, #loginform p {
                            display: inline;
                            color: red;

}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="loginsignupform">
        <div class="tabs">
            <div id="logintab"> login </div>
            <div id="signuptab"> sign up </div>
            <div id="skiptab"> skip </div>          
        </div>

        <div>
            <div id="loginform"> 

                <div class="username">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"/>
                </div>

                <div class="password">

                    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"/><Br/>
                    <p> invalid username or password! </p>
                </div>

                <p id="loginbtn"> login </p>

            </div>

            <div id="signupform" >
                <input type="text" placeholder="full name" name="name" /><br>
                <p> full name is required </p><br>
                <input type="username" placeholder="username" name="username" /><br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail"/><br>                   
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" /><br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="re-enter password" name="password1" /><br>
            </div>

            <div id="signupbtn">    
                    <p > sign up </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @MohamedAmrSalem try opening the fiddle in multiple browsers. You'll see that the code I posted above works in IE, Chrome and firefox. There might be other css elsewhere in your files that is overriding what I posted here and causing it to display incorrectly.

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you opening the jsfiddle link at the top of my post? It works in every browser.

Comment: I tried IE and chrome both appeared with same errors that appears in this screen shot http://postimg.org/image/gyfbk2pcv/ @CBauer

Comment: Are you opening the jsfiddle at the top of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

Instead of float:left, Use display:inline; and fot testing do align center. And, resize it. Its working fine for me.

HTML

```
<div id="loginsignupform" align="center">
```

to

```
<div id="loginsignupform">
```

CSS

```
#signuptab {
  float: left;
}
```

to

```
#signuptab {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided corresponding padding for `tabs`

Check this updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ruavcstx/2/

Check out the CSS changes. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks Khaleel but its not working when zooming and when using it on different browser: http://s21.postimg.org/76gzis0cn/upload.png

Comment: @MohamedAmrSalem you welcome ! for zoom scenarios there are many workarounds to find the browser zoom/resize event. using that you can detect browser zoom level and scale your whole rendered page using CSS transform, so it ll look like same but bigger.